# how to access elements that are dynamic (mongodb node js)?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose

SCHEMA: Login.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LoginSchema = new Schema({
  uname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pass: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  feeds : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = Login = mongoose.model('login', LoginSchema);
```

Now in the js code I am doing this:

```js
const newLogin = new Login({
        uname: 'guest',
        pass: 'guest',
        'random_key': 'random_value'
      });
    console.log(newLogin);
    await newLogin.save();

Login.find({uname: req.body.uname}, function (err, logins) {
            console.log("cool: ",logins[0].uname);
        }

    });
```

and it works!! the console shows this:

```js
docker-node-mongo | MongoDB Connected
docker-node-mongo | { feeds: [],
docker-node-mongo |   _id: 5fab94031fd61f00121e0a13,
docker-node-mongo |   uname: 'guest',
docker-node-mongo |   pass: 'guest',
docker-node-mongo |   random_key: 'random_value' }
cool:  guest
```

but if it type this: (an attribute not mentioned in the schema (dynamic in nature)) in the js file:

```js
const newLogin = new Login({
        uname: 'guest',
        pass: 'guest',
        'random_key': 'random_value'
      });
    console.log(newLogin);
    await newLogin.save();

Login.find({uname: req.body.uname}, function (err, logins) {
            console.log("cool: ",logins[0].random_key);
        }

    });
```

the console shows this:

```js
docker-node-mongo | MongoDB Connected
docker-node-mongo | { feeds: [],
docker-node-mongo |   _id: 5fab94031fd61f00121e0a13,
docker-node-mongo |   uname: 'guest',
docker-node-mongo |   pass: 'guest',
docker-node-mongo |   random_key: 'random_value' }
cool:  undefined
```

The issue here is the value in the console.log("cool": login[0].random_key) is showing undefined. It is an attribute not mentioned in the schema. What is the work around for this? How to output this attribute?
Thanks.

Comment: Consider looking into https://github.com/Automattic/monk, a MongoDB API for node.js that is a more direct port of the mongo shell. It does not take any schemas, which might be more useful for your (admittedly odd) use case of dynamic schemas.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is  outputting *random_key* on `console.log(newLogin)` and not after `await newLogin.save();`, is that on saving the information,  the key *random_key* is not defined in your schema.  Please fix it to be like this;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LoginSchema = new Schema({
  uname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pass: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  random_key:  {
    type: String,
    required:  true
  },
  feeds : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = Login = mongoose.model('login', LoginSchema);
```

Refer to [Schema defines your database](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: The problem is not that. In the future I will need to add random attributes. That's why I chose mongodb overmysql. Bcuz mongodb is not structured. It can have dynamic attributes. So I want to create a new attribute and access it